# iOS WriteRoom editor feature replacement?

Tags: ios, dropbox

One of my favorite features about WriteRoom is that as soon as I open it, I see a listing of a Dropbox directory I have previously configured. No extra steps. This lets me very quickly get to my notes and records without navigating around, since I always want to go to the same directory.

[Since WriteRoom will soon become incompatible with iOS 11 since it is a 32-bit app and is not being actively developed](http://support.hogbaysoftware.com/t/long-time-wr-user-on-ios-any-update/2653), does anyone know which of the many text editors available has this feature?

Per @patrix suggestion, here are prioritized features for a Dropbox text editor:

1. Open directly to a particular Dropbox folder at launch, after a one-time configuration step. No additional navigation. Speed is #1!
2. Sync that Dropbox folder's contents to the device, so that it can be accessed offline, and the changes reconciled after coming back online
3. Text search through the entire folders files, and also within the file once it is open.
4. Sort the folder list by name or date, descending.

Comment: Without the bounty the question most probably would have gotten put the on hold for lack of research. Can you at least please have a look at https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation and update your question accordingly? Having an easy access to Dropbox files is probably not the only feature a replacement needs, it also will help to know which apps you've already looked at.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is [Ulysses](https://ulyssesapp.com/). A pleasant, focused writing experience combined with effective document management, fast syncing and flexible export make Ulysses the first choice for writers of all kinds.

Here is some [info](https://ulyssesapp.com/blog/2016/08/ios-dropbox/) about synchronisation with Dropbox. A quote from that post really describes the function you are searching for.

> Once your Dropbox account is linked, you can navigate through its hierarchy and choose folders to add to Ulysses’ library.

*I do not have financial ties with Ulysses!*

Comment: Bounty is yours since you're the only answer!

Comment: I received a recommendation from a friend to try 1Writer, and though it doesn't strictly open directly to my Dropbox folder, it's pretty close so I will be giving it a trial run.

Answer (score 2):

WriteRoom for iOS is back developed and named Writemator. Wrtemator support ios 11- ios 9. Based on the WriteRoom app for iOS. Check out this Hog Bay Software Forum link: [Writemator on Hog Bay Software Support Forum](http://support.hogbaysoftware.com/t/writeroom-for-ios-lives-on-as-writemator/3437)